# How to check if object has partner

Tags: python, django

I have:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Purchases(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('User')
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product')
    data = models.DateField()
```

I'm listing products and I'd like to check if user already bought it today.

how to do something like this in template:

> PRODUCT 1 - [buy]
>
> PRODUCT 2 - [buy]
>
> PRODUCT 3 - ALREADY BOUGHT TODAY!

Comment: You want to show that depending on what? User?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the following method to your `Product` model:

```
from django.utils import timezone

def available(self):
    return not self.purchases_set.filter(data=timezone.now().date()).exists()
```

Then, in your template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{ product }} -
    {% if product.available %}
        [buy]
    {% else %}
        ALREADY BOUGHT TODAY!
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```